# How to write EXIF data in rendered images?

Tags: image, file-format

I'm trying to render an image in cycles. version 2.83.5. trying to write metadata or Exif data into the image. In the output channel, I ticked every box on metadata. But I didn't find the EXIF data included in the image, especially focal length and focal length equiv 35mm. I am using exiftool and exiv2 to check the EXIF data, the tools tell me there is no EXIF data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the [fine manual says](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/media/image_formats.html) only png, jpg, and openEXR file formats support writing EXIF metadata. So you'll have to write to one of those. openEXR is only supported in 2.93.

Focal length equivalent isn't available, and nor is sensor size.

That said, when I output png and openEXR with 2.93 it works, so if it's not working in 2.83, you may have encountered a bug.