Is there an method/add-on to save render settings as image meta-data?
I often experiment when producing final renders and, currently, just make a note of settings changed until I reach the desired result.
It would be amazing if there was a way to embed the render settings into the image meta-data or even produce a text file with the same name as the image that has all the render settings used.
That way if I decide after doing 7 tests and deciding test 04 was the best, I can look up the settings used for that render and re-apply them.
Is something like this possible with an add-on or by writing a python script?
Thanks!

Could you provide some more context? What render engine are you using? Which render settings are you interested in?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95237/custom-render-stamp-python-newline https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199820/how-to-write-exif-data-in-rendered-images
